# Does the "protection symbol" in Harry Dresden "Birds Of A Feather" exist in some mythology?

Tags: magic, the-dresden-files, symbols

Does the "protection symbol" (which Harry said it should protect from anything trying to harm the person) have any "real" origin in some mythology?

[image]

It looks slightly similar to Nordic runes and also reminds me some Icelandic magical staves ... I am just curious.

thanks

PS: the whole video seems to be officially available on DailyMotion: 
http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x4zigd0

Comment: It seems to be a poor man's "[Tetragrammatron](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=pOtTWsrvM-vfgAbp146wDg&q=Tetragrammaton&oq=Tetragrammaton&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.109678.109678.0.110289.1.1.0.0.0.0.81.81.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.78....0.bGJUXGeh1P8#imgrc=kfJc1VaoSLDSPM:)"

Comment: Which makes sense, since the series was a poor man's Dresden Files. :)

Comment: So much potential......   Wasted.